# LTSpice change output voltage of gate

Tags: ltspice

I am using the latest LTSpice on OSX (Mac). I have an AND gate which receives 10V for the in values X and Y respectively. The out signal is 1V despite the signals to the gate being 10V. How do I change the signal coming out a gate to either be a specific voltage when activated or be the same as the voltage in?

Comment: Open up the help and searched in "*LTspice > Circuit Elements > A. ...*"  [RM: edited]

Comment: Set Vhigh=10 under Value. If you want same as input voltage, you’ll probably be best off with a behavioral voltage source.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen There is no "Circuit Elements" under LTSpice. This is my first day using LTSpice, first two hours. Most of the time have been spent reading what to actually assemble in LTSpice to learn how the different circuits and LTSpice work. I have made both google search and stackexchange search which yields no answer. [RM: Edited]

Comment: @winny it only changed the plot's top value to be 10V, the output is still 1V

Comment: Ah! You’re setting the plot settings. Right click on your AND gate and enter Vhigh=10 under value.

Comment: @winny that also worked! Thanks a lot for the assistance. Worth noting that I also solved it by changing the Vlow because of the changed ref value! One can see what I mean in my other post, my answer.

Comment: Two comments edited. A slightly gentler approach on both sides would be appreciated. [Motives are not questioned - but reactions are not always as one may expect].

Answer (score 5):

How to solve the issue:

**(1) right click the logical component**

**(2) write "*Vhigh=5 Vlow=0 Ref=1.0*" into the SpiceLine option (or SpiceLine2 depending on output).**

I had an issue where the newly calculated Ref (which is "(Vhigh - Vlow)/2" value was too high when "Vhigh=5" was my only option. Furthermore it is not required to have the unit [V] after the value, as it is already implied.

Comment: You need commas between the parameters.

Answer (score 2):

### Setting Output characteristics of idealized behavioral gates

*Although a year later, I thought I may contribute a more complete answer with reference to the documentation I found*

From the documentation on the ltwiki site [LTSpice Help : A.Special Functions](https://ltwiki.org/LTspiceHelp/LTspiceHelp/A_Special_functions_.htm)

**INV**, **BUF**, **AND**, **OR**, and **XOR** are generic idealized behavioral gates and their output characteristics are set with these instance parameters:

| Name | Default | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Vhigh | 1 | Logic high level |
| Vlow | 0 | Logic low level |
| Ref | .5*(Vhigh+Vlow) | Input logic threshold |
| Trise | 0 | Rise time |
| Tfall | Trise | Fall time |
| Tau | 0 | Output RC time constant |
| Cout | 0 | Output capacitance |
| Rout | 1 | Output impedance |
| Rhigh | Rout | Logic high level impedance |
| Rlow | Rout | Logic low level impedance |

*Other special functions such as SCHMITT, SCHMTBUF, SCHMTINV, DFLOP, VARISTOR, and MODULATE are also documented in that link*

I am working on windows and to modify each component I do the following:

1. place the mouse over the component
2. Hold Down the Left Control Key
3. Right (Second button) Click the mouse *(This opens the Component Attribute Editor)*
4. Add/modify the Value of the **Attribute** **SpiceLine** to include the text `Vhigh = 10`

[image]